# Can't Acces Configure Method in my Plugin

Tags: nopcommerce

I am developing a plugin in nopcommerce and uptill now i was able to get access Configure() method in my controller.

But suddenly I found i could not access my Configure() method and so not its view.

I have put debug point as well over there, but it doesn't hit so now, i don't understand how it happens without giving any error.

I have removed whatever code and changes I have done but still problem is not solved.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Could you post the code in your plug-in controller?

Answer (score 0):

As Max suggested, it would be helpful if you are able to post your code for us to help troubleshoot.

In the mean time, please ensure that your route is set up properly in your Plugin's RouteProvider.cs. An example is at https://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Plugins/Nop.Plugin.DiscountRules.CustomerRoles/RouteProvider.cs

Please check to make sure that it matches your plugin's name/assembly's name/namespace etc. Its a good bet that one of those do not match up in your RouteProvider.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the GetConfigurationRoute method to your provider class like this:

```
public class XyzProvider : BasePlugin, IMiscPlugin
    {
        private readonly XyzObjectContext _context;

        public XyzProvider(XyzObjectContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void GetConfigurationRoute(out string actionName, out string controllerName, out RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
        {
            actionName = "Configure";
            controllerName = "Xyz";  
            routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary { { "Namespaces", "Nop.Plugin.Other.Xyz.Controllers" }, { "area", null } };
        }
```